# Proving there cannot be infinitely many sequence values not equal to the sequence's limit

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

For the sake of a larger proof, I am trying to show that if $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n} = M$ and $M \neq q$, there cannot be infinitely many elements of $x_{n}$ equal to $q$.

I felt like this would be easily provable using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit, but am unsure if my work is an acceptable proof at all.

*My attempt:*

By the definition of a limit, we are given that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N(\epsilon) \text { s.t. } n > N(\epsilon) \implies |x_{n} - M| < \epsilon $.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there are infinitely many elements of $x_{n} = q$. Then for every $N(\epsilon)$, there exists $n > N(\epsilon)$ such that $x_{n} = q$. But we know by the definition of a limit that past some $N(\epsilon)$, $M - \epsilon < x_{n} < L+ \epsilon$. Hence, we require that $q = M$, a contradiction.

$$\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the freedom to choose $\varepsilon$.

Since $q\ne M$, let $\varepsilon=\dfrac{|q-M|}{2}>0$.

Then, by the definition of limit, all but finitely many terms of the sequence are in the interval $(M-\varepsilon,M+\varepsilon)$, which does not contain $q$, and so all but finitely many terms are different from $q$.

Comment: I'm sorry, two questions. 1. What justified your choice of $\epsilon$? I don't really understand why you placed it over $2$ in particular... was it just to ensure that $q$ is not contained in the interval? and 2. Is my attempt incorrect because I sort of assume that $q$ is not contained in the interval at the end? Many thanks.

Comment: @EricHansen, yes, the choice of $\varepsilon$ is just to  ensure that $q$ is not in the interval.